# Getting most-up-to-date information in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-player

### Quick Summary

I want to be able to watch a video, and create some note at a given timestamp I am at in the video. I am currently using [react-player](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player) library to stream the video, and react/redux project created with CRA. I am finding it difficult to get the up-to-date timestamp of the video upon creating the note.

### Details

Main components of interest are two sibling components. For simplification, let's say we have an `App.js` file, which contains `VideoPlayer` component and `AddNoteButton` component.

Here is what's happening right now in each component, very simplified

#### VideoPlayer

```js
export function VideoPlayer() {
  const player = useRef(null);
  const playing = useSelector(selectPlaying);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <ReactPlayer
      ref={player}
      onPause={() => {
        dispatch(setPlaying(false));
      }}
      onPlay={() => {
        dispatch(setPlaying(true));
      }}
      onProgress={(progress) => dispatch(setProgress(progress))}
      playing={playing}
    />
  );
}
```

- `playing` and `progress` are all saved as redux states.

#### AddNoteButton

```
export function AddNoteButton() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [start, setStart] = useState();
  const progress = useSelector(selectProgress);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const showModal = () => {
    dispatch(setPlaying(false)); // dispatches action to stop playing player
    setStart(progress.playedSeconds);
    setVisible(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={showModal} />
      <Modal title="Add Note" visible={visible}>
        <div>{pauseStart}</div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

#### Issue

When user clicks the button in AddNoteButton, the following happens:

1. It dispatches `setPlaying(false)`, which changes the `playing` state in redux as false
2. A modal is shown using current timestamp of the player
3. Upon seeing updated value of `playing`, `ReactPlayer` stops running

Note, that between 2, 3 there is a short period of time where the player has not stopped. Hence, what we see is a timestamp in the note retrieved from redux state at the creation time of function `showModal`, which is not necessarily where the actual `ReactPlayer` is stopped at (it is always earlier) Ideally, we would want to create a note at `player.current.getCurrentTime()` *after* it has stopped. Is there a way to go on about achieving this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Awesome first question. Unfortunately state updates are async and it makes sense you are having this issue. You need a way to set the timestamp in the client at the same time that the media stops in the client.

Answer (score 0):

can you put the `showModal` call in the `onPause` callback prop of react-player? I think this would reverse the order of your steps 2 and 3, so the modal is shown after the player pauses and hopefully has the correct timestamp

Comment: Unfortunately that would not work, as onPause is invoked whenever the player is paused. Hence that modal would pop up whenever video is paused, which is not a behavior we want.